# jquery find all hidden input fields with specific class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a couple of table rows and tables with hidden input fields and values. What i need to do is loop through all the hidden input fields and find a specific field where the class = 'something' and value = something and go up to the `<td>` of that input field and change the background color.

```
 $('input:hidden').each(function(){
    if( $(this).find(".id_schedule_hours") && $(this).val() == 1) {
        console.log('here')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.each()` is not necessary; you can use attributes selector, `.closest()`

```
$("input:hidden[class='something'][value='something']")
.closest("td").css("backgroundColor", /* color */)
```

Comment: can you tell me how to do multiple checks such as class='something' value = 'something' and class='something2' and value = 'something2'

Comment: @Yeak _"how to do multiple checks such as class='something' value = 'something' and class='something2' and value = 'something2'"_  How can `input` element have more than one value? Can you include `html` at Question? Try `$("input:hidden.something.something2[value*='something'][value*='something2']")`

Comment: @Yeak Note, _"how to do multiple checks such as class='something' value = 'something' and class='something2' and value = 'something2'"_ does not appear at original Question

Comment: No i meant check against multiple input fields so check against a hidden field with class something and value something1 and another hidden field with class something2 and value something 2

Comment: @Yeak _" No i meant check against multiple input fields so check against a hidden field with class something and value something1 and another hidden field with class something2 and value something "_  This description appears to be beyond scope of original Question? What do you mean by "check against a hidden field"?

Comment: Ok assume i have 2 hidden fields one is id_schedule_hours and one is id_truck and and i want to find teh two hidden fields where id_schedule_hours = 1 and id_truck = 2 and update the parent td class

Comment: You would use either approach described at Answer or comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679178/jquery-find-all-hidden-input-fields-with-specific-class-name/38679281#comment64738232_38679281. See https://jsfiddle.net/qy52hcn3/

Comment: No you not understanding. I have two different hidden input fields one with class something and one with class something 2 and i want to check both and say change the background color where the input field something is equal to something and the input field something 2 is equal to something 2

Comment: @Yeak What you are describing at comment is different than description at issue at original Question?

Comment: I have just added another answer to allow you to check the value against the individual input - using a data attribute that you can set for each input field and then chack that data attribute against the value.

Comment: @gavgrif _"have just added another answer"_ How does this address original Question? Neither `.each()` nor `data-*` attribute is necessary to return expected result described at original Question

Comment: Hi - @guest271314 - sorry added answer to accomodate further requirements based on OP's comments

Comment: @gavgrif Hi. OP's requirements appeared clear at original Question, not as clear at comments which added requirements not described at original Question; in either instance, `.each()` and `data-*` attributes are not needed to return expected result

Answer (score 1):

to add unique values to be checked against - you could use data attributes and set the desired value to check against in a data variable. Then in the function - you get the data attribute value (irrespective of the input class) annd compare the value of that desired value:

```
//HTML
<input type="hidden" class="id_schedule_hours" data-desiredvalue="1" name="id_schedule_hours" value="" />

<input type="hidden" class="id_trucks" data-desiredvalue="2" name="id_trucks" value="" />

//js
$('.id_schedule_hours,id_trucks').each(function(){ 
      var desiredValue=$(this).attr('data-desiredvalue');
      if( $(this).val() == desiredValue) {
            console.log('here');
            $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the class as a selector and use .parent() to go up the chain and change the parent:

```
 $('input[type=hidden].id_schedule_hours').each(function(){
      if( $(this).val() == 1) {
            console.log('here');
            $(this).parent().css('background-color','red');
      }
 });
```

Would also suggest changing your selector name - it seems wrong to have a class called .id_...

Also - if the only inputs that class are the hidden ones you are interested in, then you can just target them directly in the selector eg:

```
$('.id_schedule_hours').each(function(){
```

Comment: The second one worked perfect is there a way to do multiple checks at once for example id_schedule_hours and id_trucks?

Comment: you can chain the selectors with a comma between them $('.id_schedule_hours,id_trucks').each(function(){

Comment: then how would i compare each value - so id_schedule_hours value = 1 and id_trucks value = 2

Answer (score 0):

You could leverage the jQuery :hidden selector. It is not part of the official CSS selectors, but a jQuery selector.

```
$('input.id_schedule_hours:hidden').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 1) {
        console.log('here')
    }
}
```

Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered to be visible, since they still consume space in the layout. During animations that hide an element, the element is considered to be visible until the end of the animation.

Elements that are not in a document are not considered to be visible; jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.

This selector is the opposite of the :visible selector. So, every element selected by :hidden isn't selected by :visible and vice versa.

During animations to show an element, the element is considered to be visible at the start of the animation.

How :hidden is determined was changed in jQuery 1.3.2. An element is assumed to be hidden if it or any of its parents consumes no space in the document. CSS visibility isn't taken into account (therefore $( elem ).css( "visibility", "hidden" ).is( ":hidden" ) == false). The release notes outline the changes in more detail.

jQuery 3 slightly modifies the meaning of :hidden (and therefore of :visible). Starting with this version, elements will be considered :hidden if they don't have any layout boxes. For example, br elements and inline elements with no content will not be selected by the :hidden selector.

See: [jQuery :hidden documentation](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)